# Center subfigure using floatrow

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, floatrow

I'm working with `caption` and `subcaption` to style my (sub)figure captions and especially with floatrow to center my figures. However, this does not work for subfigures, as the following nMWE (nearly minimal) example illustrates:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz,floatrow,hyperref}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} %link to top of figure

% caption format
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelsep=space,indention=-2cm,labelfont=bf,width=.9\textwidth,skip=.5\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}

%center both ?
\floatsetup[figure]{objectset=centering}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{objectset=centering} %does not center subfigures

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{First}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}%\centering is not centered without centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{First}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Second}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Describing both subfigures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, the first figure gets centered and everything is fine. Though, comparing the second figures subfigures, I have to use `\centering` (illustraed in the second subfigure) to center, which does not work, by using `\floatsetup[subfigure]`.

I would like to center subfigures without using `\centering`, but using a global package command. Any ideas how to obtain such layout using `floatrow`?
Any other approach is of course nice too, it's just, that i'm already using `floatrow` to center figures (globally).

PS: I'm using XeLaTeX, but I hope that does not change much in these observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you have [included `floatrow` twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148250/using-usepackage-twice-with-the-same-package-name).

You can use `ffigbox` inside a `figure` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,floatrow,hyperref}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} %link to top of figure

% caption format
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelsep=space,indention=-2cm,labelfont=bf,width=.9\textwidth,skip=.5\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}

%center both ?
\floatsetup[figure]{objectset=centering}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{objectset=centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{First}
\end{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
 \begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
   \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{First}}
  \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
   \end{tikzpicture}}{\caption{Second}}%
  \end{subfloatrow}%
 }{\caption{Describing both subfigures}}
\end{document}
```

**Allergy notice**: some parts of the above code might be nuts (or needless)

---

To answer your questions in comments (from the `floatrow` [package manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf)):

> Another command which creates figures - `\ffigbox` - puts caption below contents. The default width of caption equals to the width of text. [...] a float box, created by the
>   `\ffigbox` command looks similar to the plain figure environment. But if you set, for example, the option `[\FBwidth]` [...] you’ll get a caption width equal to the width of picture [...]

There are similar boxes where the caption is placed elsewhere (eg: `\fcapside` places it beside the figure). As far as I know `\floatsetup[subfigure]{objectset=centering}` doesn't effect the `subfigure` environment of the `subcaption` package but these boxes.

---

If you hate this stack you can *hope* that is only my overcomplicated solution and there are better ones. Or you may want to try `xpatch` (or `etoolbox`) to do the "global" subcaption centering stuff (instead of using `floatrow` for that) as a "hail mary"...

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% \subcaption@minipage is the last macro call in \subfigure (and \begin{subfigure})
\xapptocmd{\subcaption@minipage}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I like your note. I'l check that code this evening. I solved the above thingy by manually centering the stuff in the document I worked on at at that time. Thanks for coming back to that topic, because I think this general centering contributes to the idea of dividing content and layout.

Comment: Could you extend your answer and explain, what `ffigbox` does compared to `subfigure` (because just semantically `subfigure` does sound better. And could you explain, what the `\FBwith`does? I think in total (`\ffigbox subfloatrow \ffigbox`... the code is a little cluttered.

Comment: I've just added some details and an alternative way and removed the `figure` environment because it wasn't needed. A little less cluttered now. `\ffigbox` stands for `figure` and `subfigure` too, you have an extra `floatrow` but the other things are the same as any use of the `subfigure` (from `subcaption`)

Comment: I like that last solution, thanks for that, though its using subcaption (which I am also loading); I like that due to the global nature.

Comment: That's exactly why I even suggested that. ;) I you want to cancel the effect for one or two figures, you can use the `\let` macro to save the original `\subcaption@minipage` and put it back when you want that.

Comment: Well, the idea of the global definition is to define a global style that is set for all figures.